# state.findIndex is not a function error with findIndex

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux

I'm passing the `id` of the object as the `action.payload` to the reducer to modify the object.

**Reducer:**

```
const initialState = {
  posts: [
    {id:1, name:'post1', number:11},
    {id:2, name:'post2', number:22},
    {id:3, name:'post3', number:33}
  ]
}

export default function newData (state = initialState, action) {

  switch (action.type) {

    case "updateNumber": {

  // find object to update
    const index = state.findIndex(({ id }) => id == action.payload);

    if (index > -1 ) {
      const toIncrement = state[index];
      const number = toIncrement.number++;

      // create new object with existing data and newly incremented number
      const updatedData = { ...toIncrement, number };

      // return new array that replaces old object with incremented object at index
      return [...state.slice(0, index), updatedData, ...state.slice(index + 1)];
    }

      // return state if no object is found
      return state;
    }

  default:
    return state
  }
}
```

But I'm getting error:  `state.findIndex is not a function`. How to find the index of the element in the `posts` array? console.log actions is giving me `{type: "updateNumber", payload: 2}` where `payload` is the element pressed.

**UPDATE1:**

```
export default function newData (state = initialState, action) {

  switch (action.type) {

    case "updateNumber": {

  // find object to update
    const index = state.posts.findIndex(({ id }) => id == action.payload);

    if (index > -1 ) {
      const toIncrement = state.posts[index];
      const number = toIncrement.posts.number++;

      // create new object with existing data and newly incremented number
      const updatedData = { ...toIncrement, number };

      // return new array that replaces old object with incremented object at index
      return [...state.posts.slice(0, index), updatedData, ...state.posts.slice(index + 1)];
    }

      // return state if no object is found
      return state;
    }

  default:
    return state
  }
}
```

So this is supposed to return the `posts` with updated `number` in the state, right?

Comment: try `state.posts.findIndex`

Comment: Errors: `Cannot read property 'number' of undefined`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your `initialState` is an `object`.

I think you meant

```
state.posts.findIndex(({ id }) => id == action.payload);
```

Or maybe change the `initialState` to

```
const initialState = [
    {id:1, name:'post1', number:11},
    {id:2, name:'post2', number:22},
    {id:3, name:'post3', number:33}
  ]
```

**Edit**
As a followup to your edit,
After your change, Now you can do:

```
const number = toIncrement.number++;
```

As `totalIncrement` will hold an object like this for example:

```
{id:1, name:'post1', number:11}
```

**Edit #2**
I think you are mutating the `state` which is not allowed in `redux`.
Try changing this:

```
if (index > -1 ) {
      const toIncrement = state.posts[index];
      const number = toIncrement.posts.number++;
```

To this:

```
if (index > -1 ) {
      const toIncrement = {...state.posts[index]};
      const number = toIncrement.posts.number + 1; // i hope this is a number and not a string!
```

Another thing, Your initial state is an object but your reducer returns an array.
Change this line:

```
// return new array that replaces old object with incremented object at index
      return [...state.posts.slice(0, index), updatedData, ...state.posts.slice(index + 1)];
```

To this line:

```
// return new array that replaces old object with incremented object at index
      return { posts: [...state.posts.slice(0, index), updatedData, ...state.posts.slice(index + 1)]};
```

Comment: `state.posts.findIndex(({ id }) => id == action.payload);` errors: `Cannot read property 'number' of undefined`

Comment: this error obviously is thrown from another line as you are not using a `number` variable in this line.

Comment: by the way with this code you are mutating the state imo: `const toIncrement = state[index]; const number = toIncrement.number++;`

Comment: I do want to increment the number with this action if that's what you mean. The error is for line: `const number = toIncrement.number++;`

Comment: Again, your state is an object not an array. It should be `const number = toIncrement.posts.number++;`

Comment: `Cannot read property 'number' of undefined` for `const number = toIncrement.posts.number++;`. I updated my question and posted the updated code. Please have a look.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155688/discussion-between-somename-and-sag1v).

Comment: I am not getting that error now. I did `const number = toIncrement.posts.number+1;` Is my `return` proper? `return [...state.posts.slice(0, index), updatedData, ...state.posts.slice(index + 1)];` The state is showing `undefined` for the component. Please help.

Comment: The entire `state` needs to be returned to be rendered with updated results isn't it? Am I right?

Comment: I think I'm wrong. I just need to update the state and not `return` it.